# Powershell variable appears to break ACL command

Tags: powershell

Please forgive the stupidity , my job role very rarely involves scripting. I came across a few scripts online and merged them together. Basically, for each user in a .csv, it creates an AD user, a home drive and finally assigns the permissions to the home drive. However, when I check the permissions on the home drive, instead of seeing "Joe Blogs" I see something like "SID 03752-572023-23289047". Can anyone help me out? At the bottom of the script you'll see the ACL rules, where $user.username is is where it goes weird. If I put the full username e.g. "Joe Blogs" it works beautifully. And if I echo $user.username it also appears beautifully.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Store the data from Users.csv in the $Users variable
$Users = Import-csv C:\UserList.csv

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
        
    $Username = $User.username
    $Password = $User.password
    $Firstname = $User.firstname
    $Lastname = $User.lastname
    $OU = $User.ou 
    $Password = $User.Password
    $Path = "\\mydomainhere\Home$\Staff\CAAccounts\$($user.username)"

        
        #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
        New-ADUser `
    -SamAccountName $Username `
    -UserPrincipalName "$Username@fromecollege.org" `
    -Name "(CA) $Firstname $Lastname" `
    -GivenName $Firstname `
    -Surname $Lastname `
    -Enabled $True `
    -DisplayName "(CA) $Firstname $Lastname" `
    -Path $OU `
    -City $city `
    -Company $company `
    -State $state `
    -StreetAddress $streetaddress `
    -OfficePhone $telephone `
    -EmailAddress $email `
    -Title $jobtitle `
    -Department $department `
    -HomeDrive "N" `
    -HomeDirectory $Path `
    -ProfilePath "C:\profiles\basic.man" `
    -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True

    mkdir $Path
    
    $acl = Get-Acl $Path
  
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user.username,"ExecuteFile", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")  
    $acl.addAccessRule($AccessRule)  
    $acl | Set-Acl $Path  
  
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user.username,"ReadData", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")  
    $acl.addAccessRule($AccessRule)  
    $acl | Set-Acl $Path   
  
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user.username,"ReadPermissions", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")  
    $acl.addAccessRule($AccessRule)  
    $acl | Set-Acl $Path   
  
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user.username,"ReadAttributes", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")  
    $acl.addAccessRule($AccessRule)  
    $acl | Set-Acl $Path    
  
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user.username,"ReadExtendedAttributes", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")  
    $acl.addAccessRule($AccessRule)  
    $acl | Set-Acl $Path   
    
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user.username,"FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")  
    $acl.addAccessRule($AccessRule)  
    $acl | Set-Acl $Path   

}
```

Many thanks!

---

When replacing $user.username in the ACL command with the actual username, it works.

When keeping $user.username instead of the actual username, it assigns a random account in SID form like "SID 042498372-234324252-34553453".

If I echo $user.username, it displays the username with no additional formatting like quotations etc, so I know the script is understanding the variable.

Comment: Use `$newUser = New-ADUser ... -PassThru` to get the newly created user object, then pass `$newUser.SID` to the access rule constructor instead of `$user.username` - this way there's no chance of resolving the wrong user.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that has fixed the issue.